# Angular UI-Router Can ui-view replace the original tag?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to be able to replace the original element tag with the template. This should basically operate the same as transclusion when using the "replace=true" property.

Comment: Have you tried use ng-view for your purposes?

Comment: I would like to use ui-view. As the entire app is built on top of it.

Comment: Do you want to use  ui-view and relace your content according to the UI routing?.

Comment: i dont think so it is a good idea because ui-router supports child states i.e. nesting of ui-view and if you remove this tag u ll never know diff between child and parent. can you pls mention what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

So in AngularJS 1.3 replace is getting deprecated because it is very hard to resolve that type of logic in all situations with all the different attributes for elements.  There are other stackoverflow articles that cover that topic better then I can.

What we had to eventually do is write a custom attribute parser to handle each element we wanted to do that with on an element by element basis but we had to have the DOM in a certain manner for ARIA support and being able to manage some existing code bases.

I guess my real question is why are you trying to do this because that would help me give you a better answer.

Comment: I asked this a long time ago. Basically the answer was no at the time. I don't really know what the situation is now, it's still probably a no. As to the reason, the reason is just that I wanted to do it that way. The situation is of course resolved in a different way now.